# Javascript global function on replacing occurences

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Is there some cleaner way of doing this instead of calling the function multiple times
thanks .
cause I wanted to use that function for comment , note and description

```
replaceOccurrences(originalString) {
    let newString;
    // eslint-disable-next-line camelcase
    const html_entity = '&num;';

    // eslint-disable-next-line no-mixed-operators
    if (originalString && originalString.includes('#')) {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-shadow
      const newString = originalString.replace(/#/g, html_entity);
      return newString;
    }
    return originalString;
  }


 let description = this.getDescription(submission.request);
            description = this.replaceOccurrences(description);

            const comment = this.replaceOccurrences(a.comment);

            let notes = this.getNotes(a, question, submissions);
            notes = this.replaceOccurrences(notes);
```

Comment: This is kind of what functions are for :)

Comment: why is this "not clean"?

Comment: unclear how if you are calling it with 3 different strings

Comment: so this is a good implementation ?

Comment: @epascarello cause they have different values

Comment: What's your definition of "good implementation"? I'm not trying to be obtuse here. These kind of things are very much based on opinions. One person's "good implementation" is another's terrible idea

Comment: @DaveLuthwerg that was my point of my comment.

Comment: maybe a better and a cleaner one

Comment: Stack overflow is not for code review. It is for problem solving which are related to programming. For code reviews visit the Code Review platform (https://codereview.stackexchange.com)